# Install Inkscape 0.91 on Debian Weezy

Tags: debian, compiling, inkscape, bazaar

There is no Debian Wheezy build of latest (0.91) stable version of Inkscape (https://inkscape.org/en/download/linux/). So i can't use Apt.
I have try to obtain source code using Bazaar.
First I install bzr:

```
apt-get install bzr
```

Then I use command

```
bzr branch lp:inkscape
```

And I have got ~400mb of files.
But I can't find any `./configure` files, and `make` command doesn't work.

Is it possible to have Inkscape 0.91 on Debian 7. And what is the easiest way?

Comment: There is a Debian build of the latest Inkspace; it's in `testing`. See https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/inkscape for version information.

Comment: note that `lp:inkscape` points to the development branch that will become 0.92.  It is not stable 0.91.  You can use the `autogen.sh` script in the top level directory of the inkscape source to generate `configure`.

Comment: @saiarcot895 It works! I have some errors during install process (for example on `fontconfig`), however for my scenario of converting svg to png it works. Thank you!

Comment: @vatavale: Unless there have been some new features related to exporting to PNG in 0.88+, that feature has been in Inkscape for a while.

Comment: @saiarcot895 In 0.43 I couldn't export SVG with <image> tags inside. Looks like it just ignored.

Comment: @vatavale: Ah, ok. Also, I didn't know Inkscape had that big of a version bump.